# Pass the ident of a shape from an svg file in c++ when clicked on

Tags: c++, c, winforms, svg

I have an SVG file that is essentially a background for a winform application.

Is it possible to get the ident of a shape when you click you on it and pass the ident name into a variable in c++?

I could then manipulate shapes on my background depending on certain conditions.

Also open to any other ideas that I could achieve this but it has to be in c++ in VS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is more a question about whatever widget you're using to display the SVG than it is about C++.  AFAIK, WinForms doesn't ship with anything that displays SVGs.  What are you using to display it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.